# Determining the order of a Graph containing an induced subgraph when Δ(G)≤ r

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

**Example in textbook asks to find a 5-regular graph H of minimum order containing G as an induced subgraph.**

They start of the solution saying δ(G) = 2 and the order of G is 6, the order of such a graph H must be at least 9. However there does not exist a 5-regular graph of order 9, so the order of H must be at least 10

This is where I get confused, where do they get the value 9? Why can the order not be 7,8,or 9, where do they derive this value? Also they state there is no 5-regular graph of order 9, is this because a regular graph cannot have an odd order and odd regularity so they just go to the next even number to choose the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph $G$ has a vertex of degree $2$, which must have degree $5$ in $H$. So it must have $3$ more neighbors that aren't in $G$, giving $3$ more vertices on top of $G$'s $6$, for a total of $9$.

You're right about the reason order $9$ is ruled out: by the handshake lemma, there must be an even number of vertices of odd degree, so if the graph is $5$-regular, there must be an even number of vertices.